# Testing an update to a cookbook on a single production server

Tags: chef-infra

We have sometimes cookbooks that can't be fully tested in staging environment as the result does not always reflect what might happen in production environment. As a solution what I'm trying to do is to freeze the version for the environment like so:

```
{
  "name": "production",
  "description": "Production Environment",
  "cookbook_versions": {
    "deployment": "= 0.1.12"
  },
...
```

and exclude a specific server for that limitation by specifying the new version explicitly in its run list like so:

```
...
  "run_list": [
  "recipe[base]",
  "recipe[security]",
  "recipe[deployment::auto_war@0.1.13]"
]
...
```

problem is, when the version of the environment is not the same as that specified in the run_list, chef-client gets stuck on `resolving cookbooks for run list: ...`

why is that? is there a way to get around this? is there a better way to test an update for a recipe only on one server?

Answer (score 2):

You can't override an existing constraint, so you would have to temporarily move that node to a new environment for testing purposes.

Comment: Unfortunately, that would defeat the purpose, as some of recipes behave differently depending on the environment of the node, meaning, the test will not reflect what will happen in production. Also, I don't think this is true, this seems basic enough to do by design. I have also discovered that chef hangs at the same place when using a specific version at the runlist even when there is no constraint. It appears it is just a bug.

Comment: The feature is rarely used be we do test it so I can say fairly confidently that there is not a (simple) bug with it. That said, even if there was, it would not work with a conflicting constraint in the environment since that error is correct and working as designed.

Comment: Another option is to disable daemon-mode or background converges in production, update the environment, and then run a canary deploy on a few machines.